# Line-graph plotting strangely; scatter plot rejects timestamp

Tags: csv, matplotlib, timestamp, scatter-plot, linegraph

I'm plotting some data imported from [a csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKFjT.jpg); a simple line graph works ok except that there are messy-looking lines where the data points connect (they're angled oddly and give the graph an overall [cluttered look)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ9BR.png).

I want to change to a scatter-plot with lines between the points, hoping that this will remove the issue. However, when I plot a scatter-plot, the datetime from my csv is rejected and the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Anx.jpg) is displayed.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can use csv datetime with a scatter-plot. Or, even better, how I can stop those annoying messy lines in a line-graph? This latter would be the ideal option.

*[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZPa7.jpg) for the .values solution...*

My code is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 

# Read the file in csv 
File = pd.read_csv("Timeline.csv") 

# Where to save the output
outputDirectory = 'Z:\\15_Hawaii\\Plotting\\'
if not os.path.exists(outputDirectory):
    os.makedirs(outputDirectory)

# Datetime selection
time = File.iloc[:,0] 
time_time = pd.to_datetime(time, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
time_time = pd.to_datetime(time_time, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
time_day = mdates.DayLocator()

# Kona data selection
Kona = File.iloc[:,2]

# defining the names which will be called
fig, host = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.gca()

# simple plot of the data
K_plot, = host.plot(time_time, Kona, color=[0,0.690196078,0.941176471], linewidth=1, label="Kona")

# attempt to scatter plot the data
K_plot, = plt.scatter(time_time, Kona, color=[0,0.690196078,0.941176471], linewidth=1, label="Kona")

# other plotting parameters
ax.xaxis.grid(linestyle='dotted')
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=80 )
fig.set_size_inches(12, 5)

plt.savefig(outputDirectory + 'SO2_PLOT_1' + '.png', bbox_inches='tight',     dpi=300, pad_inches=0.0)
```

Comment: Can you try `K_plot = plt.scatter(time_time.values, Kona.values, color=[0,0.690196078,0.941176471], label="Kona")`?

Comment: Hi ImportanceOfBeingErnest, when I add in .values to the scatter variables, it does produce a scatter plot, but with the TypeError "PathCollection" is not iterable. I'll add a screenshot of this to my original post so you can see...

Comment: There is no comma after `K_plot` in my suggestion.

Comment: Ah! I missed that, but it seems to have fixed it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, from the image, your imported dataframe's first row contains the strings 'Date', 'Time' and 'Kona_data'.  If you read from the second row like this, then does the problem persist?

```
time = File.iloc[1:,0] 
Kona = File.iloc[1:,2]
```

Comment: Hi Anotherone, unfortunately removing the csv headers doesn't seem to have any effect on the scatter plot, the "invalid type promotion" error is still displayed. :(